# Customize NavigationView panel to include image UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to customize `NavigationView` on UWP C# XAML to have static app image at the top side of left panel which wont redirect to a page but rather just the app icon.

The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) only mentions displaying App title using `Canvas.Index` 0/1 option and customizing background.

```
<NavigationView OpenPaneLength="200"
                x:Name="navigationView"
                SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
                Header="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}"
                IsSettingsVisible="True"
                IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="True"
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}">
```

[image: Corresponding Nav panel]

I would like to customize this to have an at least 100x100 pixels image, at the top.

**What have I tried? :**
I tried the below code, but the image occupies only the icon space at the left.

```
<NavigationViewItem>
    <Image Source="/Assets/Cubes/purple.png"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

[image: Image 2]

```
<NavigationViewItem>
    <Image Source="/Assets/Cubes/purple.png"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"></Image>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

[image: image 3]

```
<NavigationViewItem Height="100">
    <Image Source="/Assets/Cubes/purple.png"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"></Image>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

[image: image 4]

**Expected**

[image]

---

Is it still possible to achieve this with `NavigationView` or do I need to use other UI elements like `SplitView` or `MasterDetailView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the root panel's height of the NavigationViewItem's ControlTemplate is set to a fixed value(40).

You could edit the NavigationViewItem's style to make it meet your requirement.

Please see my following sample:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem" x:Key="test">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                    <Grid
                    x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <!-- Wrap SelectionIndicator in a grid so that its offset is 0,0 - this enables the offset animation. -->
                        <Grid 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            <Rectangle
                            x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                            Width="6"
                            Height="24"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}"
                            Opacity="0.0"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <Border
                        x:Name="RevealBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                        <Grid Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="ContentGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox"
                            Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                            Margin="16,12"/>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTip" />
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I set `Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"` for the 'LayoutRoot' Grid, then you could apply this style to your NavigationViewItem like the following:

```
<NavigationViewItem Style="{StaticResource test}">
    <Image Source="/Assets/Cubes/purple.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"></Image>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Comment: Sorry, hadnt checked. This works as desired,Thanks a lot. Although I want to disable `OnItemInvoked(NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)` only for this Image. Getting `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to type 'System.String'.'`

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me. Example:
Write `<NavigationViewItemHeader>` in `<NavigationView.MenuItems>`. like

```
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationViewItemHeader Height="180">
        <Image Source="/Assets/Cubes/purple.png" Width="320" Height="180"/>
    </NavigationViewItemHeader>
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```